# Insert matplotlib's Path into Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to insert a matplotlib Path object into a numpy array, what dtype should be used?

Here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np

dtypes = np.dtype([('Shape', '<f8', (2,)), ('FIELD2', '<U254'), ('FIELD3', '<U254'),
                   ('FIELD4', '<U254'), ('FIELD5', '<i4'),
                   ('Length', '<f8'), ('OID@', '<i4')])

b = np.array([([ 93.59900552,  22.62355019], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.59901266,  22.6233646 ], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.59901623,  22.62300054], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.59913044,  22.62273999], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.59924109,  22.62261507], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.59925536,  22.62240805], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.59936601,  22.62212966], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.59954804,  22.6220083 ], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.59976219,  22.62173348], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1),
 ([ 93.60013339,  22.62131588], u'randomtext', u'atext', 9999, 1, 1.2119301339479824, 1)],
             dtype=dtypes)
```

I want to convert the points to a  matplotlib path object, but when I  set the dtypes to:

```
dtypes = np.dtype([('Shape', object), ('FIELD2', '<U254'), ('FIELD3', '<U254'),
                   ('FIELD4', '<U254'), ('FIELD5', '<i4'),
                   ('Length', '<f8'), ('OID@', '<i4')])
```

Then convert the `matplotlib.path.Path()` doing the following:

```
new_array = np.array([], dtypes)
for id in set(b['OID@'].tolist()):
    sub_array = array[np.where(array['OID@'] == oid)]
    geom = matplotlib.path.Path(sub_array['Shape'])
    row = list(sub_array[0])
    row[0] = geom
    new_array = np.array([row], dtypes)
    new_arrray = numpy.vstack([sub_array, new_array])
```

Thank you

Comment: Why the down vote?  It's a simple question.

Comment: That's the problem - the question is too simple.  `insert` itself is ambiguous.  Does the array already exist, or are you trying to make an array can contain these objects. etc?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @hpaulj - added more information, up vote you downvote.

Comment: I didn't vote on your question, but hopefully my answer shows how that initial simple question was woefully inadequate.  Even with your edits it was struggle to figure out what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After puzzling over your edits, and experimenting, I think this what is going on:

With your `dtypes` I can make an 'empty' array

```
In [995]: dtypes
Out[995]: dtype([('Shape', 'O'), ('FIELD2', '<U254'), ('FIELD3', '<U254'), ('FIELD4', '<U254'), ('FIELD5', '<i4'), ('Length', '<f8'), ('OID@', '<i4')])
In [996]: x=np.empty((3,),dtypes)
In [997]: x
Out[997]: 
array([(None, '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0), (None, '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0),
       (None, '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('Shape', 'O'), ('FIELD2', '<U254'), ('FIELD3', '<U254'), ('FIELD4', '<U254'), ('FIELD5', '<i4'), ('Length', '<f8'), ('OID@', '<i4')])
```

`np.array([],dtypes)` is the same as `np.empty((0,),dtypes)`; a zero element array of this dtype.  That's only good for repeated `stacking`.

I can make a `Path` object with:

```
In [1000]: apath=matplotlib.path.Path(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2))
```

The `Shape` field has `dtype=object`; so I can assign any object to it

```
In [1001]: x['Shape']
Out[1001]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)

In [1002]: x['Shape'][0]=apath
In [1003]: x['Shape'][1]=matplotlib.path.Path(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2))
In [1004]: x
Out[1004]: 
array([ (Path(array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.]]), None), '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0),
       (Path(array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.]]), None), '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0),
       (None, '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('Shape', 'O'), ('FIELD2', '<U254'), ('FIELD3', '<U254'), ('FIELD4', '<U254'), ('FIELD5', '<i4'), ('Length', '<f8'), ('OID@', '<i4')])
```

Or for a single element array:

```
In [1010]: y=np.empty((1,),dtypes)
In [1011]: y['Shape']=apath
```

Maybe this is closer to what you are trying:

Use an element of a dtypes array as 'template':

```
In [1012]: x[2]
Out[1012]: (None, '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0)
In [1013]: row=x[2]
In [1014]: row[0]=apath     # assign `apath` to a slot
In [1015]: row
Out[1015]: 
(Path(array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.]]), None), '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0)
```

`row` is a `np.void` object, not a list or tuple

I can make an array that contains this object:

```
In [1016]: np.array(row,dtypes)
Out[1016]: 
array((Path(array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.]]), None), '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0), 
      dtype=[('Shape', 'O'), ('FIELD2', '<U254'), ('FIELD3', '<U254'), ('FIELD4', '<U254'), ('FIELD5', '<i4'), ('Length', '<f8'), ('OID@', '<i4')])
```

But `[row]` does not work

```
In [1017]: np.array([row],dtypes)
...
ValueError: Setting void-array with object members using buffer.
```

turning the `np.void` into a tuple does work.  In general structured arrays are created or filled a list of tuples (or field by field).

```
In [1018]: np.array([tuple(row)],dtypes)
Out[1018]: 
array([ (Path(array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.]]), None), '', '', '', 0, 0.0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('Shape', 'O'), ('FIELD2', '<U254'), ('FIELD3', '<U254'), ('FIELD4', '<U254'), ('FIELD5', '<i4'), ('Length', '<f8'), ('OID@', '<i4')])
```

`row` and `tuple(row)` display the same, but clearly for this purpose they are not the same.

So if I've read things right, this really isn't a `Path` object issue; not even a `dtype=object` issue.  It's about creating a structured array.

Comment: correct, the issue is trying to create the structured array using the dtypes specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a numpy array of a python object, you can use

```
np.empty(shapeInformation, dtype = object)
```

and then fill the array with whatever pythonobject you like

Comment: when I set the column to object using ndtypes, it fails with:  Setting void-array with object members using buffer.
dtype([('Geometry', 'O'), ('DEFICIENCY', '<U254'), ('FEATURE_CLASS', '<U254'), ('SUBTYPE', '<U254'), ('ORIG_OID', '<i4'), ('DEFICIENCY_CNT', '<i4'), ('Shape_Length', '<f8'), ('OID@', '<i4')])

Comment: np.empty((2,2), dtype = object) works fine on my machine. Please provide some example code, then I can try to help you further.